# Random vector (X, Y) uniformly distributed on triangle

Tags: probability

Suppose that a random vector (X, Y ) is uniformly distributed on the triangle $\{(x,y) : x + y <= 2 , x >= 0, y >= 0\} $ Compute:

a) $P(X+Y\le1)$

Since $\int\int c \ dxdy = 1$ and $c=1/2$ (i.e. area of traingle is 2), we have $\int_0^1\int_0^{1-x} 1/2 \ dy dx$

b) Conditional density of X given Y=y

$p_{X|Y}(x,y)= p_{X,Y}(x,y)/p_Y(y) = (1/2) / \int_0^2 1/2 \ dx $

Is this formulation correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The integral you got for a) is correct. It would be easier, for the case of constant density, to find the **ratio** of the area of the triangle with corners $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, and $(0,1)$ to the area of the triangle with corners $(0,0)$, $(2,0)$, and $(0,2)$.

This ratio is not hard to compute.

For b), the expression for the conditional density is correct. But (for suitable $y$) 
$$p_Y(y)=\int_0^{2-y} \frac{1}{2}\,dx=\frac{2-y}{2}. $$
Note that the "formula" we get is only valid for a certain range of values of $x$, that depends on the value of $y$.